# Inteceptors doesn't work in Message Driven Bean

Tags: jakarta-ee, interceptor, message-driven-bean

I was trying to use method level interceptor from message driven bean. But i use it, interceptor was not called but when i used interceptor on class level or if put @interceptors(sampleInterceptor.class) on onMessage method it's working.

Any body has any idea why interceptors is not being called when you put @interceptors(sampleInterceptor.class) on any private methods in Message driven bean?

I am using glassfish server 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to ejb3.1 specification:

> Interceptor methods may be defined for business methods of sessions beans and for the message listener methods of message-driven beans.

A [message listener method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpo.html) must follow several rules, one of them is:

> The method must be declared as public.

Comment: Yes, It worked. Thanks! You have to declare methods in another session bean, and then you can call that method from that message driven bean.